# 13.10 broke radeon HDMI audo

Tags: sound, radeon, hdmi, 13.10

Makes me so angry that after finally figuring out to modify grub configuration to set radeon.audio=1 13.10 update killed my audio.
Zero sound through HDMI.

How to fix this?

Dell Zino HD.

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you please restate your question to ask for a solution? "Anyone else experience this?" is considered an [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) question here. Thanks and have nice stay!

Comment: On another note: Did your set that kernel command line parameter again after upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately after upgrading my Dell Studio 1535 HDMI output is not available anymore, too. It worked before, `radeon.audio=1` is known to Grub and editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` did not fix the problem, too.

Reinstalling Pulseaudio and Alsa several times did not help although no output is muted in Alsamixer.

But, after selecting an older 3.8 instead of 3.11 Kernel in Grub2 I was able to get HDMI audio working again!

**After installing the mainline 3.11.6 kernel the HDMI output works, too.**

Comment: Thanks man! Gave my audio back. From where did you install that kernel version 3.11.6? It is not on the official repositories...